# PDO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE not work on PHP 5.1.6

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tables`
    (
        `uuid`,
        `name`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        :uuid,
        :name
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `name` = :name
    ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':uuid', 'abc');
$sth->bindValue(':name', 'Chan');
$sth->execute()
```

When I execute code first time, it's insert correct data to table, but when I execute second time, `name` value turns to 0, even I change name to other value get the same result, but if I do it like:

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO `tables`
    (
        `uuid`,
        `name`
    )
    VALUES
    (
        :uuid,
        :name
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `name` = 'other name'
    ";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':uuid', 'abc');
$sth->bindValue(':name', 'Chan');
$sth->execute()
```

The `name` value become `other name`, how to fix it?

Comment: Holy crap! You are using 5.1.6? That one released in 24 Aug 2006? with plenty of security holes http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.6

Comment: Sir, the company I worked use it, I hate that too :*(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't use the same parameter name more than one time. So try the following

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tables`
(
    `uuid`,
    `name`
)
VALUES
(
    :uuid,
    :name
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    `name` = :name2
";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':uuid', 'abc');
$sth->bindValue(':name', 'Chan');
$sth->bindValue(':name2', 'Chan');
$sth->execute()
```

EDIT: See the comment below

Comment: Or alternatively, `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = VALUES(name)`.  See [`VALUES()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values).

Comment: Which would be the more elegant solution

Comment: But when I execute in my own environment, PHP 5.5+, it's work perfectly

Comment: Anyways, I just use `VALUES(\`name\`)`, although it looks ugly :(